# Textarea focus doesn't start at the top

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/8T8Xe/3/ - with two fields. The left field is an input and the right field is a textarea. If you enter something into the left field and hit Enter, the field turns green and the cursor moves to the textarea field. But the cursor moves to the bottom of the text area field instead of the top.

Does anyone know how I can start focus at the top of a textarea field?

Thanks.

```
 <input type="text" id="store_name">
 <textarea id="product_description"></textarea>
```

Comment: It's not going to the bottom of the textarea, it's going down one line in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `keydown` to `keyup`. Problem solved. The "enter" is being applied to the textarea after the move when using the former. http://jsfiddle.net/8T8Xe/5/